# Autocomplete web addresses in Safari on OS X Lion?

Tags: safari

I'm really digging the built in gesture support in Safari for OS X Lion. However, I'm sorely missing the "Awesome Bar" functionality (ala Chrome & FF).

Any way to enable this option in Safari?

Comment: Exactly the same with me, also the lack of an omni/super bar is just plain archaic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Safari Omnibar Plugin solves this. I've been using it successfully on Safari 5.1 on OS X Lion.

http://www.pimpmysafari.com/SafariOmnibar-GitHub-271/